# Is it possible to define multiple 'names' in Flex/Lex?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to run `flex` on the following file with the arguments `-lfl`.
I am received by the following errors:

```
romans.l:14: name defined twice
romans.l:16: name defined twice
romans.l:17: name defined twice
romans.l:19: name defined twice
romans.l:22: name defined twice
romans.l:23: name defined twice
romans.l:24: bad character: \
romans.l:24: unknown error processing section 1
romans.l:24: unknown error processing section 1
romans.l:24: bad character: {
romans.l:24: unknown error processing section 1
romans.l:24: unknown error processing section 1
romans.l:24: bad character: }
romans.l:25: unrecognised '%' directive
flex: can't open -lfl
```

Let's ignore the other errors in my code for the moment, as I am confused as to why there exists an issue with lines 14 through 23. To the best of my knowledge, there shouldn't be an issue with what I am trying to do. Here is my lex file.

```
  1  %{
  2 // file created via echo
  3 # include <studio.h>
  4 # include "roman.tab.h"
  5 %}
  6 I{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
  7 V{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
  8 X{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
  9 C{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
 10 L{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
 11 D{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
 12 M{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
 13 CM      { yylval = 900; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* NINEHUNDRED */;}
 14 M       { yylval = 1000; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* THOUSAND */ ; }
 15 CD      { yylval = 400; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FOURHUNDRED*/;}
 16 D       { yylval = 500; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FIVEHUNDRED*/;}
 17 C       { yylval = 100; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return HUNDRED*/;}
 18 XL      { yylval = 40; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FOURTY*/;}
 19 L       { yylval = 40; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FIFTY*/;}
 20 IX      { yylval = 9; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return NINE*/; }
 21 IV      { yylval = 4; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FOUR*/; }
 22 V       { yyval = 5; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return FIVE*/; }
 23 I       { yylval = 1; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /*return ONE*/; }
 24 \n      { return EOL }
 25 %
```

Numbers at the front are just the line numbers (copied from vim with :setnumber flag enabled).

I am assuming the fault has something to do with "return ARABIC_NUMERAL" line, but no where have I seen that this is explicitly against the rules of lex? Scratching my head here genuinely and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Turns out it was those comments in each of the line... should have copt onto that earlier

Comment: There's a semicolon missing from line 24.  Personally, I'd not have put the comments before the semicolon, but that's me.  Line 22 sets `yyval` and not `yylval`.

Comment: I'm not sure the Copts appreciate being confused with 'copped' :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this — using `%%` before and after the matching rules instead of `%`, etc.

```
%{
// file created via echo
#include <stdio.h>
#include "roman.tab.h"
%}
%%
I{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
V{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
X{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
C{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
L{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
D{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
M{4}    { yyerror("syntax error");}
M       { yylval = 1000; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* THOUSAND */; }
CM      { yylval =  900; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* NINEHUNDRED */; }
D       { yylval =  500; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FIVEHUNDRED */; }
CD      { yylval =  400; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FOURHUNDRED */; }
C       { yylval =  100; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* HUNDRED */; }
XC      { yylval =   90; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* NINETY */; }
L       { yylval =   50; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FIFTY */; }
XL      { yylval =   40; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FORTY */; }
X       { yylval =   10; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* TEN */; }
IX      { yylval =    9; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* NINE */; }
V       { yylval =    5; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FIVE */; }
IV      { yylval =    4; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* FOUR */; }
I       { yylval =    1; return ARABIC_NUMERAL /* ONE */; }
\n      { return EOL; }
%%
```

I 'fixed' `studio.h` to `stdio.h`, inserted a missing `;` (after `EOL`) and a missing `l` (in `yylval` for `V`), and changed the second `40` to `50` (and the spelling of 'forty').  I added the `XC` and `X` rules — you seem to have overlooked 90 and 10.

I also made the alignment and comments more symmetric; consistency is very important in programming.

The second `%%` is optional; the first is not.

You supply the `-lfl` option to your compiler when linking; you do not provide it to `flex` when converting the source.  That's why you got the error about `-lfl` not being found.

Comment: Yes yes, the comments didn't have any affect, but the error "name defined more than once" had disappeared and I assumed I fixed it. The %% was a rookie mistake.. as was studio.h and the missing letters :